# Show the selected option as the first option in the select dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-select-search

I am using react-select to show a list of users in a dropdown. I want it to always show the selected element as the first element in the list. Is there native support for this?

Example:

In the following image, since `Green` is selected, I want `Green` to appear at the top of the list before `Ocean`

[image]

Comment: Add your code so that we can identify your implementation

Comment: Here is the link to the code from which I added this screenshot. However, I feel it should not be related to my implementation as I'm looking for native support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code :

```
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([
    { label: "Blue", value: "Blue" },
    { label: "Red", value: "Red" },
    { label: "Yellow", value: "Yellow" },
    { label: "Green", value: "Green" },
    { label: "Pink", value: "Pink" },
    { label: "White", value: "White" },
    { label: "Brown", value: "Brown" }
  ]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Select");
  function handler(e) {
    setValue(e);
    let newOptions = [];
    newOptions.push({ label: e, value: e });
    for (let i in options) {
      if (options[i].value !== e) {
        newOptions.push(options[i]);
      }
    }
    setOptions(newOptions);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        name="colors"
        defaultValue={value}
        options={options}
        onChange={(e) => handler(e.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Click this link to view [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-tag-customization-1c38z)

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to do this sorting myself.  I was checking if there is built-in support for the same. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an initialize callback to `useState` to sort the `options` array for the first time and put the `defaultValue` on top:

```
function sortOptions(options, selectedValue) {
  return options.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a === selectedValue) return -1;
    if (b === selectedValue) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
}
```

```
const defaultValue = colourOptions[5];
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState(() =>
  sortOptions(optionsProp, defaultValue)
);

return (
  <Select
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    onChange={(value) => setOptions(sortOptions(optionsProp, value))}
    name="colors"
    options={options}
  />
);
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Actually, I want this behavior not just for the default value, but also when the user selects other options. Moreover, I can figure out a way to do it manually, I was just wondering if react-select has built-in support for it.

Comment: @ArjunMudhaliyar I just skim the [docs](https://react-select.com/props#prop-types) and looks like there is no such option. Updated my answer for completion anyway.

Comment: I was afraid so. In any case, thank you for adding this manual solution :)